# 'jss' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: sitecore, jss

I am new in Sitecore JSS. 
While running the following command using CMD:

```
npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli
```

I got the following result:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4
>   (node_modules@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> - @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@9.0.6 updated 1 package in 21.068s

After that I wanted to check that JSS has been installed successfully, so I ran the following CMD command:

```
jss --help
```

but the result was:

> 'jss' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

What am I missing?

Comment: For me this worked.https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/13319/2311

Answer (score 5):

Check your environment path variable.

Default the npm location on Windows is
C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm

There you found a jss.cmd and the node_modules\@sitecore-jss folder.

To fix the "'jss' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." error add the npm location to your path or shortly %AppData%\npm

To add somethings to the path go to  control panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings then environment variables.

if you cant found the npm location try

> npm config get prefix

Comment: really thank you Jan,It is working fine. you saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

It is an issues with NPM and this specific version of @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@9.0.6.
It is recommanded to use yarn to fix for now. Until the next jss-cli release.

Make sure you remove (@sitecore-jss, jss and jss.cmd) from

```
C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Roaming\NPM\
```

Install Yarn globally : https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-stable
Re-install @sitecore-jss/jss-cli using Yarn

```
yarn global add @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli
```

Make jss is using it, using this command

```
where jss
```

Expected result:

```
C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\jss
C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\jss.cmd
```

if not, try to refresh you environment variables using

```
refreshenv
```

(or restart your Command Prompt)

Comment: thank you mohamed for your answer. it is working fine with Jan answer.